# use a QVector pointer in slots and signals

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

Sorry for the disturbance, i am trying to pass a QVector as pointer from MainWindow to a Dialog, the code is running but the output says : 
`QObject::connect: No such slot SystrayDialog::receiveSystrayIcons(<QVector<SystrayIconsData>*)`

I do not understand everything about signals and slots yet, am doing exercices to understand well, please find my code:

**mainwindow.h**

```
...
signals:
    // transmit objects to dialogs here
    void emitSystrayIcons(QVector<systrayIconsData> *icons);
...
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
...
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
...
// initialize Systray Settings Window Dialog
    sDialog = new SystrayDialog(this);

    // Create Connectors from and to dialog here
    connect(this, SIGNAL(emitSystrayIcons(QVector<systrayIconsData>*)), sDialog, SLOT(receiveSystrayIcons(QVector<SystrayIconsData>*)));
}
// Slots
void MainWindow::showSystraySettingsDialog()
{
    sDialog->setModal(false);
    //sDialog->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    sDialog->show();
    sDialog->raise();
    sDialog->activateWindow();
}
...
```

**systrayDialog.h**

```
class SystrayDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
...
// Icon Datas
    QVector<systrayIconsData> *stIcons;
...
private slots:
    // receive objects/data from MainWindow or other component here
    void receiveSystrayIcons(QVector<systrayIconsData> *icons);
}
```

**systrayDialog.cpp**

```
...
// Slots
void SystrayDialog::receiveSystrayIcons(QVector<systrayIconsData> *icons)
{
    stIcons = new QVector<systrayIconsData>();
    stIcons = icons;
}
...
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: `connect(this, SIGNAL(emitSystrayIcons(QVector<systrayIconsData>*)), sDialog, SLOT(receiveSystrayIcons(<QVector<SystrayIconsData>*)));`

in this line <QVector<SystrayIconsData>* has extra `<` is it typing error ?

Comment: it's indeed a typing error, sorry for this, but the error is still the same

Comment: This is one reason a [mcve] that you can copy-paste is so important. If you copy-paste code into the question instead of rewriting it, you won't get such errors (or, hopefully, other unrelated errors or problems).

Comment: Typo: `SystrayIco...` --> `systrayIco...`?

Comment: again `receiveSystrayIcons(QVector<SystrayIconsData>*)` doesn't exist but 
`void receiveSystrayIcons(QVector<systrayIconsData> *icons);` exists

Comment: mm i guess you don't get it , the typing error was in the code directly, i change and reexecute and didn't get any evolution, sorry, but i do my best to respect everything when i ask  a question ...

Comment: Maybe you could try to connect signal/slots Qt5 way to prevent typing issues.

e.g `QObject::connect( &m_srv , &QTcpServer::newConnection , this , &prc_proxy::on_new_client );`

Comment: ok many thanks, now i don't have the error, but the Values in vecotr are still not readable, will check further on this matter before asking for help if required.
i don't understand this typo error , because i always use "tab" to complete my keywords to prevent this cases, maybe i forgot on this one ...

Comment: OK just for information, everthing is solved now, many thanks, the last issue was taht i didn't emit the signal when i raised the window, once i add it , my signal and slot worked like a charm.

Sorry once again for this beginner question, but i now grab a little more how signals and slots are working...

Comment: No worries. Btw, if you use C++11 and most recent Qt I would use lambdas in slots. It saves you a lot of time.

Comment: Signals and Slots internally are just function pointers. The signal is a function pointer created through the Qt-Framework (MOC) whenever you tell him this through your class definitions. The same goes for slots. So when through a trigger the signal func pointer gets called, the defined slot is executed. Of course there is more than that, because there exist the event queue managing all this, but basically that's the whole magic.

Comment: I would suggest to use the new (checked at compile-time) syntax. In almost all cases you’d also want to pass the vector via const reference instead of via pointer (who is deleting your vector?)